# Animating d3 line graph from 'left to right' instead of 'right to left'

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, graph, charts

I am trying to animate the drawing of a d3 line from left to right. I wrote the below piece of code long ago which animates it from right to left. Revisiting it now to change the direction. Kinda lost and been breaking my head on it for quite some time now. Can anyone please help me out. Really appreciate it :)

```
var totalLength = lines.node().getTotalLength();
lines.attr('stroke-dasharray', totalLength + " " + totalLength).attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1000)
                        .ease("linear")
                        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Comment: This code looks like it's going to draw the line from left to right.

Comment: Like Lars said, your code already draws from left to right. If you want to draw from right to left, simply change the second `stroke-dashoffset` to `totalLength*2`.